# How to clear a line in Vim

Tags: edit

I want to achieve the same thing as `S ESC` without entering insert
mode. Is there a way to do this?

The best I've come up with is `d$`, but then you have to make sure
you're at the front of a line which makes it `^ d$`.

Visually, with cursor as `|`; before:

```
Beautiful sentence that I wa|nt to destroy.
```

After:

Comment: What about `dd`?

Comment: @DDS: That deletes the line, OP wants the line to remain but empty.

Comment: Just curious: is there any problem with entering insert mode? Is it slower? Is it even noticeable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To save one keystroke, instead of `^d$`, do `^D`

Also faster because you keep the Shift key down for both `^` and `D`

Comment: `cc<esc>` in another way to do it (or `S<esc>`).

Comment: "Also faster because you keep the Shift key down for both ^ and D". On Qwerty keyboards. On mine, I have to press ^ twice (without Shift) in order to get ^. So it would be ^^+Shift-D. cc<esc> is indeed faster.

Comment: @Biggybi `S<esc>` was specifically called out in the question as undesired because OP doesn't want to enter insert mode. The same thing would apply to `cc<esc>`.

Comment: @8bittree indeed you're right (that's why I only bring it in a comment, not an answer).

Comment: @8bittree: Just curious: is there any problem with entering insert mode? Is it slower? Is it even noticeable?

Comment: @EricDuminil Probably better to ask young_souvlaki. All I can think of is maybe to avoid triggering an autocommand. Or to avoid having to reach for the `<esc>` key.

Comment: I've been using `0D`.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to set a `:h omap` for a line.

For example :

```
onoremap il :<c-u>normal! $v0<cr>
```

Then you can use `dil` to *delete inside line*. Of course, `yil` would yank the line, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no blanking line command. I imagine you would need to make your own mapping

```
nnoremap gS :<c-u>call setline('.', '')<cr>
```

I am not sure how useful that would be

Answer (score 1):

Well, to add to all the answers:

1. `:pu_|-d<CR>` which you can map to, for instance, `:nnoremap dr :<C-u>pu_|-d<CR>`
2. create a text object "a line" and delete a line with `dil` or `dal` (and this could be a fancy one to operate on screenlines for example)

```
" line text object
func ObjLine(inner)
    if a:inner
        " for non-wrapped line following works:
        " normal! g_v^
        " but I want to handle wrapped
        normal! g$
        search('\S', 'cb')
        normal! vg^
    else
        normal! $v0
    endif
endfunc
xnoremap <silent> il :<C-u>call ObjLine(1)<CR>
onoremap <silent> il :<C-u>normal vil<CR>
xnoremap <silent> al :<C-u>call ObjLine(0)<CR>
onoremap <silent> al :<C-u>normal val<CR>
```

[image]

Comment: Distinguishing `il` and `al` for leading spaces is quite smart!

Comment: @Biggybi not only leading, trailing too.

Comment: Indeed -- good thing you point this imprecision.